# Git 1.8.x locking windows domain accounts

Tags: git

We are using git as a version control system.  The master git repo interfaces with the windows domain controller so it can leverage our domain username and passwords as git credentials (one less credential to remember).  We push/pull to this master from both windows and linux development environments.  The Linux boxes have different credentials than the windows/git systems.

Last night we upgraded our from git 1.7.1 to git 1.8.3 on our linux machines only.  Overnight all of our accounts started getting locked out because of too many unsuccessful login attempts.  I have noticed a git-remote-http process with several child git processes now running periodically on the linux machines *even when no git actions are being performed on the machine* (which I find strange).

Has anyone experienced this particular problem? Does anyone know of differences in how git handles credentials from these two versions?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The git version was a red herring.

The actual thing that was causing this was upgrading to SmartGit 6, which, amongst its many new features, includes "background fetching" to track remote changes. I am guessing this just constantly does git fetch against the remote, which might be helpful if it were using the right credentials.  You can turn this off by going to Edit -> Preferences -> Background Commands and unchecking "Detect Remote Changes"